# gem path reverts back to previous path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

just recently installed ruby 2.3.0 and rails 4.2

ran bundle install for the first time and my app successfully ran from my local server.

added a few gems, and once again ran bundle install... it appears that my previously installed gems were once again being installed.

tried running rails server once again and this came out.

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/rails: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

just making a wild guess here, but i think the gem folder is reverting back to my old folder which is ruby 1.9.1

any form of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are managing your rubie installs? Have you tried using a ruby manager such as chruby or rbenv?

Comment: im using rvm. funny because it doesn't seem to remember the previously installed gems and the error points out to an old ruby directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read about different ways to set the app/project environment at [rvm project workflows](https://rvm.io/workflow/projects)

if you are using `rvm` to manage the `rubies`, just add this line at the top of your gem file..

```
ruby '2.3.0' #or the target version of the app
```

or

```
#ruby=2.3.0
```

and `cd` back into the directory.. you'll get a warning but just ignore it. now every time you change back to you app directory it'll change the version to the one mentioned in your gem file. the default might be set to some other version..

you can also use

```
bash --login
rvm use '2.3.0' --default
```

to set the default version of ruby system wide.

if that doesn't work.. try to check if the correct `ruby` version is present by

```
rvm list
```

and then try using it by

```
bash --login
rvm use '2.3.0' #or the target version
```

and to every time switch to the latest version don't do anything above except when installing the version set it to default.. but you'll have to install all the gems again for every binary ruby you install..

**P.S. Fixing ruby version for a project/app is a good and safe practice, so I'd recommend you to use the any approach to fix a ruby version for the app, mentioning it in Gemfile is clean, makes sense to me when you only need to set the ruby version.**

## Note. Do whatever is in @***Shrikant1712***'s answer first if you haven't already or you might run into issues.

Comment: works like a charm, how do i permanently set the ruby version? turns out that i have 2 versions. gemfile path is not pointing out on the latest version.

Comment: unfortunately there is no way to point to the latest version.. each time you install it.. you need to change the version inside the `Gemfile` or while in your project directory execute this `rvm --ruby-version use 2.3.0 # the version.` .. but make sure to remove the line `ruby '2.3.0'` or it might cause some issues.

Answer (score 0):

You have need to install gem bundler using `gem install bundler` command and then again try to use `bundle install` command.

(Here I am assuming you have used RVM for installing ruby.)

Still you get same type of error then that means your rvm is not properly set.  Please check your $PATH from the following files

- ~/.profile
- ~/.bashrc
- ~/.bash_profile
- ~/.gemrc

You can use `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` for setting the rvm.